# How to fix “Error opening block database”?

Tags: bitcoin-core, database

[How to fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUNWS.jpg)

[image]

My computer shut down without closing the program and now I try to help the network but cannot open the app... I'm a newbie, excuse myself please!

Answer (score 3):

May you have corrupted files due to shutdown.                   I’ve suggest you to take a look at the debug.log file for further information. First try the -reindex option if you continue to have this issue there Remove the corrupted files and restart Bitcoin core again. Note: You should backup your wallet file before any operation.